# slideDown a div with anchor click then go to link

Tags: jquery, onclick, href, slideup

I want to have a jquery div slide down on a click of a anchor tag, which is working but I want it to animate first and then visit the clicked link. Is this possible?

```
   $('#portfolio').click(function() {
        $('#bodyG').slideUp('fast');
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#portfolio').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#bodyG').slideUp('fast', function() {
    window.location = href;
  });
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();`, a common culprit! :)